# Stop moving the images when any of its sides touch the canvas sides while zooming and move

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scale, drawimage

I have developed zoom in and zoom out functionality in html5 canvas. When my image sides touch sides of canvas, it should not get redraw further. I want functionality like this. http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/

After zooming the image refer to 2nd canvas box and try to move the image. The moving of image stops when image side overlaps with canvas side.

**html**

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <button id="carregar">Load Imagem</button>
            <button id="giraresq">Rotate to Left</button>
            <button id="girardir">Rotate to Right</button>
            <button id="zoomIn">+ Zoom</button>
            <button id="zoomOut">- Zoom</button>
            <button id="moveImage" disabled="true">Press do move imagem with mouse</button>
        <hr />
        <canvas id="canvas" height="567" width="682" data-girar="0" data-scale="0">       </canvas>

        <script>

      window.onload = function()
      {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var image=document.createElement('img');
            image.onload = function () 
            {
                  element.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            }
            image.src="images/desert.jpg";

            var element = canvas.getContext("2d");

            //set delta for zoom and keep track of current zoom
            var zoomDelta = 0.1;
            var currentScale = 1;

            //set delta for rotation and keep of current rotation
            var currentAngle = 0;
            var startX, startY, isDown = false,flag_allow=false;
            var counter_zoom_out=0;


            jQuery('#zoomIn').click(function () 
            {
                counter_zoom_out=counter_zoom_out-1;
                currentScale += zoomDelta;
                if((canvas.width*currentScale>=canvas.width) &&         (canvas.height*currentScale>=canvas.height))
                {
                    flag_allow=true;
                }
                //alert(currentScale.toString());

                drawImage("IN");
            });

            jQuery('#zoomOut').click(function () 
            {
                counter_zoom_out=counter_zoom_out+1;
                try
                {
                  if(counter_zoom_out<3)
                  {
                      currentScale -= zoomDelta;
                      if((canvas.width*currentScale<=canvas.width) && (canvas.height*currentScale<=canvas.height))
                      {
                          flag_allow=false;
                      }
                      drawImage("OUT");
                  }
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });

            canvas.onmousedown = function (e) 
            {
                var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
                startX = pos.x;  //store current position
                startY = pos.y;

                isDown = true;   //mark that we are in move operation
            }

            canvas.onmousemove = function (e) 
            {
                  if (isDown === true) 
                  {
                      var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
                      var x = pos.x;
                      var y = pos.y;
                      //translate difference from now and start
                      var initial_width=canvas.width*currentScale;
                      var initial_height=canvas.height*currentScale;

                      if( (initial_width==canvas.width && initial_height==canvas.height) )
                      {
                          flag_allow=false;
                      }

                      if(flag_allow)
                      {
                        element.translate(x - startX, y - startY);
                      }

                      drawImage();
                      //update start positions for next loop
                      startX = x;
                      startY = y;
                  }
            }

            //reset move operation status
            canvas.onmouseup = function (e) 
            {
                isDown = false;
            }

            function getMousePos(canvas, evt) 
            {
                var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                return {
                    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
                    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
                };
            }

            // Function to clear canvas
            function clear() 
            {
                try
                {
                    // I have lots of transforms right now
                  element.save();
                  element.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                  // Will always clear the right space
                  element.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                  element.restore();
                  // Still have my old transforms
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    alert(err);
                }
            }
            var sw,sh;
            function drawImage(in_out_val)
            {
                try
                {
                    //alert("drawImage");
                    clear();
                    element.save(); //as we now keep track outselves of angle/zoom due to
                                    //translation, we can use save/restore
                    element.scale(currentScale, currentScale);
                    element.rotate(currentAngle * Math.PI / 180);
                    sw=canvas.width*currentScale;
                    sh=canvas.height*currentScale;

                    if(in_out_val==="IN")
                    {
                        if((sw<canvas.width) && (sh<canvas.height))
                        {
                            drawImage_in_middle_after_zoom_out(sw,sh);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          element.drawImage(image,-sw/2+canvas.width/2,-sh/2+canvas.height/2,sw,sh);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        drawImage_in_middle_after_zoom_out(sw,sh);
                    }
                    element.restore();
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    alert(err);
                }
            }

            function drawImage_in_middle_after_zoom_out()
            {
                var loc_x=((canvas.width-sw));
                var loc_y=((canvas.height-sh));

                element.drawImage(image,loc_x,loc_y,sw,sh);
            }
      };

    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
canvas 
{
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:#000;
}

img
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think most easy way to handle those cases is to always compute a *next* value based on user imput, then clamp the value, then assign it to be the new value.

```
nextX += x - startX ;
nextY += y - startY ;
```

This would involve using a clamp function :

```
function clamp(x, minx, maxx) {
     if (x<minx) return minx;
     if (x>maxx) return maxx;
     return x;
}
```

Then

```
 x = clamp(nextX, 0 , canvas.width - scale * image width );
 y = clamp(nextY, 0 , canvas.height - scale * image height );
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working.Following is my updated function.

Comment: nextX += x - startX ;
      nextY += y - startY ;
      
      x = clamp(nextX, 0 , canvas.width - (currentScale * image.width) );
       y = clamp(nextY, 0 , canvas.height - (currentScale * image.height) );
      
      startX = x;
                  startY = y;

Comment: ok, but you know S.O. is not about providing final working answer but rather guidance. It seems you made it, great !